# How to fire up SQL Exception from CATCH it T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, try-catch, raiserror

Assuming I have the following table

```
Create Table [T] ([id] int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary key, [value] varchar(200))
```

Now I want to set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`, but if it fails to set it back to `OFF`

So I have the following:

```
BEGIN try
  set IDENTITY_INSERT [T] ON
  insert into [T]([id],[value]) values(1,'test')
  set IDENTITY_INSERT [T] OFF
END try
BEGIN catch
  set IDENTITY_INSERT [T] OFF
  --RAISERROR ?
END catch
```

Now I want to fire the error up im manner the caller will receive the exact error(include number, arguments, severity etc.. 
As if I called to `insert into [T]([id],[value]) values(1,'test')` On non-IDENTITY table.

I mean to sumething like throwing the exception from a catch

```
try{
  ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  throw e;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I think there is examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) no?

Comment: @Sami If I set the `ErrorMessage`, does it set the `ErrorNumber` too?

Comment: Did you try something like `RAISERROR ('Msg', -1, -1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to re-throw the error that took you into the CATCH? Than just use THROW without any parameters. You can't use RAISERROR for that since you cannot set both error number and text, nor can you refer to a system-error. So, just THROW will do that.

Comment: Thanks, It works when adding a ';' after the  previous line

Comment: Yep, THROW is one of those pretty rare constructs that require that previous command was ended with semi-colon.